# Setting PRODUCT_NAME on command line causes test failure

Tags: ios, unit-testing, continuous-integration, xcodebuild, xctest

In my main target I have a user defined build setting CI_PRODUCT_NAME. It is set as part of my CI build. This is used to set the product name of the target's output by setting the Product name build setting to ${CI_PRODUCT_NAME}

This all works fine and other build settings I've defined all work as expected. The issue is the tests don't run with the following command:

`xcodebuild -workspace workspace.xcworkspace -scheme scheme -configuration Debug CI_PRODUCT_NAME=test_product clean test`

At first I received a linker error telling me my main target could not be found, this was due to the BUNDLE_LOADER value now not matching, so I updated it by adding a user defined build setting on my test target of CI_PRODUCT_NAME and setting the BUNDLE_LOADER value to:

`$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/${CI_PRODUCT_NAME}.app/${CI_PRODUCT_NAME}`

The original linker error has gone but now I am receiving:

`The test bundle at DerivedData/Scheme-edjkzeakmzewtyckdurvlrjvvxrs/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SchemeTests.xctest could not be loaded because a link error occurred.  It is likely that dyld cannot locate a framework framework or library that the the test bundle was linked against, possibly because the framework or library had an incorrect install path at link time.`

I have tried a few things, it seems if I set the value of CI_PRODUCT_NAME on my main target in the xcode project to match the value passed in the command line the tests work. The tests also work when the values match in xcode and they are run through xcode.

It seems as if the CI_PRODUCT_NAME value passed on the command line is being ignore for the main target at one of the build stages, but there is no indication whats going wrong until I receive the above error